# magento2 checkout: how to update billing address programmatically

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs, billing-address

I would like to force update of the billing address as user is typing his firstname and lastname in the checkout. For example when it changes or on keyup.

I'm using a custom checkout module that only triggers this update when the postcode is changed or the country is changed.

I was thinking of creating a mixin for `set-shipping-information` and monitor the elements so I can trigger this action but I honestly can't find any guide on how to approach this.

I tried writing my mixin like this

```
define([
'jquery',
'mage/utils/wrapper',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-billing-address',
], function ($, wrapper, quote, selectBillingAddress, ) {
'use strict';

return function (setShippingInformationAction) {


    $(document).on('change',"[name='firstname']",function(){
        console.log('firstname changed');
        //code to update billing address 
    });


    return wrapper.wrap(setShippingInformationAction, function (originalAction) {
        return originalAction(); // it is returning the flow to original action
    });
};
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the solution to my own issue. In case it helps someone else in order to update the billing address you need to utilize the component

```
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
```

Then you can use the following functions to force an update to both shipping address and the billing address.

```
resolveShippingAddress()
resolveBillingAddress()
```

to update the values on the addresses.

I'll post here my full example with some debugging commands that helped me better understand what's happening as well in the console.log

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
], function ($, wrapper, quote, checkoutDataResolver ) {
    'use strict';

    return function (setShippingInformationAction) {

        var checkIsAddressSameAsShipping= function(){
          var $checkbox = $('billing-address-same-as-shipping');
            return !!$("input[name='billing-address-same-as-shipping']:first").is(':checked');
        };


        $(document).on('change',"[name='firstname']",function(){
            console.log('firstname changed');
            if(checkIsAddressSameAsShipping()){
                console.log({shipping: quote.shippingAddress()});
                console.log({billing: quote.billingAddress()});
                console.log({checkout: checkoutDataResolver});

                checkoutDataResolver.resolveShippingAddress();
                checkoutDataResolver.applyShippingAddress(checkoutDataResolver.resolveEstimationAddress());
                checkoutDataResolver.resolveBillingAddress();
                checkoutDataResolver.applyBillingAddress();
                console.log({shipping2: quote.shippingAddress()});
                console.log({billing2: quote.billingAddress()});
            }
        });


        return wrapper.wrap(setShippingInformationAction, function (originalAction) {
            return originalAction(); // it is returning the flow to original action
        });
    };
});
```

I would still like to know if there's a recommended way to do it though from someone more experienced.